# What's the best method to semantically structure a form?

Tags: html, forms, semantics

I've seen several examples of how developers structure their forms using tables, divs, and lists; all of which are not very semantic. What is the best method for structuring an HTML document so it breaks each label & input group to the next line and can be easily read - **without the use of CSS**?

(I feel that ol's and ul's are simply a replacement for tr's and td's. A form, in my opinion, is not a content or definition list)

I almost feel like div's are the best format since a div is a clear 'division' or grouping of items but I'm not sure.

Sample HTML

```
<form>  
    <fieldset>  
        <legend>Your Favorites</legend>  
        <label for="color">Color</label>  
        <input id="color" name="color" type="text" />  
        <label for="food">Food</label>  
        <input id="food" name="food" type="text" />  
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>  
    </fieldset>  
</form>
```

Comment: This is pretty subjective. However, I would recommend `ul` or `dl`. Is a form somehow not a list of inputs?

Comment: A UL is not semantic? Not true. It is a collection (or list) of form elements.

Comment: @bookcasey - No, it's a set of fields. Hence the element `<fieldset>`

Comment: @ScottSimpson - It's not that `<ul>` is not semantic. It's a question of whether or not it carries the wrong semantics.

Comment: @Alohci - while what you are saying about a form being a set of elements is true, a `<fieldset>` can contain a list of elements which wouldn't achieve the OP's goal of separating the different label/input combinations visually - hence the use of `<ul>`. In order to express semantic meaning you use attributes, specifically `class`, `id` and in, some cases, `rel`.

Comment: @Alohci -- buttons and checkboxes are fields?

Comment: @ScottSimpson - I would argue that checkboxes and buttons are fields. Checkboxes are multi-selects with different a visual representation. Buttons are a bit harder: they have fairly distinctive characteristics compared to other field types. They do accept user input (i.e. mouse clicks) and they do have values (which, admittedly, can't be changed by the user) - in practice they're usually used to submit forms and not much else but they can be used for capturing data just as is the case with a text box.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Be careful not to get semantics and structure confused. HTML elements exist, primarily for expressing structure. Semantics is about giving the structure meaning. While there is a *some* semantic meaning in *some* HTML markup, it is very generic meaning. So my answer is broken along those lines:

**Semantics**

Why is it important for you to express semantic meaning through your form? Is the markup supposed to be consumed by a client other than a standard browser? Is it a special use-case?

If you need to infuse semantic meaning to the elements of your form do so by decorating your structural markup with appropriate classes and ids - you won't likely get any semantic meaning from the HTML elements in your form regardless of which element type you use to group/separate your inputs.

**Structure**

- If you're just looking to provide visual separation of inputs and want to use the least possible markup then use `<br />` tags after your inputs.
- If you want to structurally group your inputs to their labels then use `<div>`, `<ul>`, `<ol>`, or `<dl>` - all of these tags can achieve this objective equally as well as the others.
- If it is important to imply, structurally, that the form elements belong together as a set then don't use `<div>` elements which indicate distinctness or separateness. List elements indicate that the different child items are a set, and, like @bookcasey says in his comment, a form is, in most cases, a *list of inputs* which belong together logically.

That's my 2c.

For what it's worth, without being able to use CSS, I'd use `<ul>` (or `<ol>` if the order is important) in this situation. When I have CSS I use `<dl>` which gives me more style control.

**UPDATE:**

In response to Alohci's arguments, I'm reversing my position about not using `<div>` elements. By wrapping them in a `form` or `fieldset` they are grouped together logically already - this alongside the use of appropriate classes (i.e. `<div class="field">` as suggested by Alohci in the comments) will provide structure and appropriate semantic meaning.

Comment: It's funny how when you think about something for so long you forget the basics.. such as the `<br />` tag. Your comments about separation of Semantics vs Structure was very helpful. I think it's because I've always considered lists to define my 'content', not my code, that I've always felt `<ul>` and `<ol>` was not the best choice.

Comment: @Zac - there are different kinds of semantics in HTML. Those that are associated with element names are there for the purpose of media independence. i.e. Browsers do something with them visually for sure, but they also expose them to the platform accessibility API in very specific ways. The question to ask yourself is, if you were blind, would you want to hear as a prompt "List item 1. Forename." or just "Forename". How has being told that the label/input pair is an item in a list helped you? How has it helped anyone else? Or is it semantics for semantics sake? ...

Comment: ... Then these are augmented by private semantics for structural and page organisational purposes. These are conveyed through the id and class attributes. Leaving aside microformats for the moment, the semantics of class and id are for the author or authoring team only. Typically using words in the author's preferred language, these semantics are then useless to anyone who doesn't speak that language and therefore are of very limited utility for sharing meaning with consumers of the HTML. ...

Comment: ... Finally, there are extended public semantics for specialised consumers such as social network sites. RDFa, microdata and microformats are all currently competing for that space. The recent big fuss over the `<time>` element in HTML5 was because the editor recognised that `<time>` didn't do anything in browsers. So it was using the wrong kind of semantic mechanism. It should have been handled by RDFa/microdata/microformat and the `<data>` element was invented to provide the hook for that. He was obliged to back down, but he had a point. ...

Comment: ... So choose your semantic markup wisely. And only ever choose a non-neutral semantics element solely to obtain a presentational effect as an absolute last resort. According to these principles, wrapping each {label, input} pair in a `<div class="field">` element meets the OP's requirement appropriately.

Comment: @Alohci - you make a thorough, well-constructed argument. I think I'll concede the point to you.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the following:

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Legend</legend>
    <label for="element-id1"><span class="label">Label</span><input type="text" id="element-id1" /></label>
    <label for="element-id2"><span class="label">Label</span><input type="text" id="element-id2" /></label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

...and set the labels to `display: block`. The `.label`s I also set to `display: block` with a set width.

I'm sure some would say that the `span` is needless markup, but it depends on how you look at it. I think it's necessary as it allows me to structure the labels for the form elements nicely thus helping usability.

-- EDIT --

After your edit, I would recommend the following:

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Legend</legend>
    <ul>
      <li><label for="element-id1">Label</label><input type="text" id="element-id1" /></li>
      <li><label for="element-id2">Label</label><input type="text" id="element-id2" /></li>  
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: I need to edit my question to include without the use of CSS, thanks for the reply though.