# What's the semantically correct HTML tag to wrap around your form label/input pairs?

Tags: html, forms, semantics

Currently I wrap a `div` around my html label/input pairs. Is that acceptable? Is it better to use `li`?

Comment: You'd only use a `<li>` as part of an `<ol>` or `<ul>`. You could use `<fieldset>` instead of `<div>`, but for this I don't think it matters. It's more to do with what semantics you're trying to show.

Comment: “Semantically” is a pointless buzzword. There is no semantics (meaning) for it in contexts like this, so the question just triggers openions and debate.

Comment: I'd question whether it is just a buzzword - it just mean it has to follow certain rules (in a way any other language, natural or compututation, does) - given HTML has rules defined in a doctype, it is sensible for someone to find out what tags can go where

Comment: Styling Form with Label above Inputs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046110/styling-form-with-label-above-inputs

Answer (score 1):

A div is fine. I don't see what's wrong with that. It all depends on how you want to style your page. A fun thing you can do with labels and input is set them up so that when you click on the label it will select the input. Do like this: `<label>Password: <input type="password"></label>`.

Comment: i prefer to use the for attribute in the label and have them unnested

Comment: What's the advantage of using the for attribute?

Comment: I think the main advantage of using the "for" attribute rather than nesting is that you can then float the label to the left if you want to, and in general it's more  flexible for styling purposes to have them as separate elements. I do like nesting the input inside the label for checkboxes and radio buttons though.

Comment: There's a good discussion of the semantic concerns here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524087/whats-the-best-method-to-semantically-structure-a-form. In short: yes, divs are fine, and probably even preferable to li elements for screen readers.

Answer (score 1):

Lately, I've been wrapping my input with my label, like so:

```
<label>Name:
    <input id="name" type="text"></input>
</label>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, `div`s are allowed. `form` is a *block level* element, and such elements can contain other block level and inline children.

If you run your code through the [W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org/), you'll find out if your code is semantically valid or not

Comment: Valid has little to nothing to do with semantic... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML

Comment: No, but he was asking if it is correct to have `div` elements as a child of form elements (I can't think of anywhere where label / input pairs wouldn't be part of a form?).  If he'd asked whether it is correct to have a `div` element as a child of a `label` tag, that would would obviously be no.  It is, to some extent a case of semantics (meta-semantics?!) whether that would be called "semantically invalid" or just "invalid HTML"

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear... Your first statement is valid. However, the W3C validator won't tell you whether or not your html document is semantically correct (unless it's had some huge improvements since the last time I used it). It will tell you if your document is syntactically correct.

Comment: Yes it does, trying to put http://jsfiddle.net/Q9CBd/ through the validator results in an error: 'document type does not allow element "div" here; missing one of "button", "map", "object", "ins", "del", "noscript" start-tag <p><div></div></p>'; modifying `<p><div></div></p>` to `<div><p></p></div>` results in 'This document was successfully checked as XHTML 1.1!'

Comment: Oh, oops - it's late here! Yes, I guess it doesn't tell you, technically, if it's semantically correct. I really think the question was trying to ask if it was valid HTML though, and misused the work 'semantic' - of course, I might be wrong!