# how to list input fields

Tags: html, forms, screen-readers

I want to make a login form as:

```
<form>
<label>Username:<input type="text" name="username"></label>
<label>Password:<input type="password" name="password"></label>
</form>
```

but some people write it as:

```
<form>
<ul>
<li><label>Username:<input type="text" name="username"></label></li>
<li><label>Password:<input type="password" name="password"></label></li>
</ul>
</form>
```

OR

```
<form>
<p><label>Username:<input type="text" name="username"></label></p>
<p><label>Password:<input type="password" name="password"></label></p>
</form>
```

first question: which way is recommended and why ? second: does any of this method will hinder reading by 'screen readers' for blind ?

Comment: This question encourages opinion-only answers unfortunately. Regardless of what you do, make sure you have `for` attributes in each of your labels if you're worried about accessibility.

Comment: I think the other way... there has to be a method which will recommended for better styling or good for screen readers

Comment: Please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524087/whats-the-best-method-to-semantically-structure-a-form it demonstrates your problem and illustrates why there is no "recommended" solution

Comment: Sounds like the only solution is research & discovery of what screen readers do in practice. I suspect that your first option might work best because, per mattytommo's link, semantically li and p have specific meanings that don't really match the purpose of form inputs, but that is speculation. I suggest you try those three blocks of code in a screen reader and see what happens. Post your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the 2nd method and here's why: 1st, you have a `<form>` element which shows you have list of elements within it. Thus, proper nesting of your unordered list items. You would have to just make certain in a stylesheet to remove the decoration, so the `<li>` tags don't appear as bulleted.

`ul li 
 {
   list-style-type: none; 
 }`

Next, the `<label>` tags are proper enough for the associated input names... no need to have to extra block element space produced by the `<p>` tag. The label conveys the input has an identity of sorts.

Lastly, regarding the effect on screen readers, as I suspected, a screen reader must be able to identify what things are on the page being parsed. It doesn't know what elements are by default. Hence, if you have a list of things, what better way use an element which embodies what you're conveying... `<ul><li></li></ul>`

Here's a link and resource which explains more of the latter for you: https://webaccessibility.withgoogle.com/unit?unit=1&lesson=5